# Sencha Touch and CORS Support (not through JSOP)

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, cors

I am trying to make an ajax call to an authenticated api called [parse](https://www.parse.com/) and sencha touch.
I am currently working on an implementation using this git code https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-basic / Video of Implementation http://vimeo.com/28821052

I get this issue when trying to make the request:

```
Origin http://127.0.0.1:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Ive tried to set the correct headers like so but no dice.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : 'true'
```

What would be going wrong here?

Comment: It looks like the issue was on parse's end. I put in question about it and they just notified me that they now proper Cors support. Woot!

Answer (score 1):

Those access control headers only work when they are sent by the API, not the client. After all, it's the API that needs to be protected from the client, not the other way around.

Unless the [parse](http://parse.com) API changes their headers, you'll have to use techniques like JSONP or a server-side proxy.

Comment: Yeah good point. Unfortunaly jsonp only supports get requests and I need access to get/post/put/delete. I wonder if I can edit sencha core to output the correct headers.

Comment: @Justin: Sencha is on the client side, you need to change the server.